# Question regarding Banach-Steinhaus theorem and statement following the theorem

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

> **Theorem A** (*Banach-Steinhaus*): Let $\{A_\alpha\colon X\to Y\}_\alpha$ be a family of bounded operator between two Banach spaces $X$ and $Y$, and assume that for any $x\in X$ there exists $C_x>0$ such that $\sup_\alpha||A_\alpha x||\leq C_x$. Then there exists $C>0$ such that $||A_\alpha x||\leq C||x||$ for every $x$ and any $A_\alpha$ from the family. This means that the set of operators $A_\alpha$ is a bounded set in $L(X\to Y)$.

> **Statement**: From the Banach-Steinhaus theorem, it follows directly that, if the sequence $\{A_n\}$ is Cauchy in the strong sense, then there exists $A\in L(X)$ such that $A_n\to A$ strong.

In the Banach-Steinhaus theorem, I'm curious as to why we take that the family to bounded? Is this to ensure that $||A_\alpha x||\neq\infty$? Regarding the statement, I'm just confused about what is going on. Since $\{A_n\}$ is Cauchy we know, by definition, that $\{A_nx\}$ is Cauchy in $X$. Since $X$ is a Banach space, the limit, say $Ax$, exists so $A_nx\to Ax$. This by definition means that $A_n\to A$ strongly. However, I assume the Banach-Steinhaus theorem is used to get that $A\in L(X)$, but I don't see how/why.

The set $L(X)$ is the space of all bounded linear operators from $X$ to $X$, whereas the set $L(X\to Y)$ is the space of all bounded linear operators from $X$ to $Y$.

Answer (score 1):

You take the family to be bounded because unbounded linear operators are discontinuous and very hard to work with (indeed, one of the most important facts of functional analysis is that a linear functional is bounded if and only if it is continuous). The continuity plays a key role in the proof.

Your argument for why the second claim should be true is faulty. It is true that $A_nx$ converges to some vector, and you can name that vector $Ax,$ but you want to argue that (a) $A$ is a bounded linear operator and (b) $A_n\rightarrow A$ in norm, not just pointwise. (a) is not so hard to argue, but Banach-Steinhaus is needed to do (b); generally, Banach-Steinhaus is a useful way of turning pointwise convergence into uniform convergence for bounded linear operators.

Comment: So how is $A$ a bounded linear operator by Banach-Steinhaus?

Comment: @D.Math You do not need Banach-Steinhaus for showing $A$ is bounded linear, this is fairly immediate from knowing it is a pointwise limit of bounded linear operators.

Comment: Oh, but you said " but you want to argue that $(a)$ $A$ is bounded linear operator", then later said "$(a)$ is not so hard to argue, but Banach-Steinhaus is needed to do".

Comment: @D.Math Banach-Steinhaus is needed to do (b) is what I asid; I meant that (a) is easy, (b) needs Banach-Steinhaus